# How to know the day of week of selected date from jdatechooser in java

Tags: java, mysql, dayofweek, jdatechooser

I am using java. I have used JDateChooser to select a date. now I want to display the day (line Sunday, Monday or else day of week) of the selected date. I know how to add JDateChooser but don't know how to get the day of week of selected date. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JDateChooser` will return an instance of `java.util.Date`, which is, frankly, less than useless now days.

The trick here is to covert the `Date` value to a `LocalDateTime` value, for example...

```
Date date = new Date();
LocalDateTime ldt = date.toInstant()
        .atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault())
        .toLocalDateTime();
```

Then you can simply query the `dayOfWeek` value...

```
DayOfWeek dow = ldt.getDayOfWeek();
System.out.println(dow.name());
```

Now you can use the `DayOfWeek#name` value or, because it's a `enum`, generate your own output as you need

Comment: Instead of ' Date date = new Date(); ' I have used ' java.util.Date date= jDateChooser1.getDate(); ' . Note I have Used java swing drag and drop . rest the code worked fine for me.

Comment: It's the good answer. A detail, if the date chooser doesn't give any meaningful time of day, I'd use `toLocalDate` to obtain a `LocalDate` rather than a `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: @meeraBisht Yeah, it was all just using it as demonstration ;)